# heimdall-frontend fails with undefines symbol error

Tags: 10.04, command-line, android

Trying to run heimdall 1.11 and here is the error i get when trying to use the program

```
heimdall-frontend: symbol lookup error:
heimdall-frontend: undefined symbol: _ZN9QListData11detach_growEPii
```

can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using QT4? And have a look here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/archive/index.php/t-1534182.html

Comment: i dont know what qt4 is and from that link i dont want to use heimdall 1.31 i want heimdall 1.11 can you help with that cause that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: he is asking if you have Qt installed. heimdall frontend will not work without it. you are using old version, so it might be better to use heimdall on the command line. you will not need extra software for that

Comment: ok so the very first command line in that xda site says "sudo apt-get build-essential"   when i do that I get this "E: Invalid operation build-essential" so i then proceed with the next two commands and they work so since i already have heimdall installed i try runnning it again and get the same error.  Please help guys.

Comment: it's sudo apt-get *install* . Seriously , use the terminal: way easier.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this particular problem you can follow the instructions [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1534182).

If you cannot even install heimdall on 10.04 then the following may help. All of the  Heimdall binaries hosted on [Benjamin's github](https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell) (including 1.1.1) require a newer version of libusb-1.0-0 (2:1.0.8) than is installed on ubuntu 10.04. I have searched on google and found a ppa on launchpad for heimdall on 10.04. **This will upgrade your libusb-1.0 also.** So these are the commands you need to run.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:modycz/heimdall
sudo apt-get update
wget https://github.com/downloads/Benjamin-Dobell/Heimdall/heimdall-frontend_1.1.1-1_i386.deb
sudo apt-get install heimdall
sudo dpkg -i heimdall-frontend_1.1.1-1_i386.deb
heimdall-frontend
```